# How to get logs from remote device

Tags: ios, logging

Our iOS app has a subtle bug which is 100% reproducible on one of the team members’ device.

He is not a programmer, so he does not use XCode.

To investigate the bug, I plan to make a custom build with logging, ask him to launch it and reproduce the bug.

The question is where to write logs to and how to get them from his device with minimal friction.

I believe that logs must be written to some local file on iPhone, and then he send me this file say by email.

Are there any ideas how to make this sharing clear and easy for a non-programmer?

Little clarification:

In my concrete case I need to log a couple of (rather long) base64-encoded string.

Comment: Crashes or bug?

Comment: @Prakash I need to log a couple of rather long base64-encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

The better way for your scenario is use slack, telegram or any chat application. Then instead log to the files, you can send log to a channel directly.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api
https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks

In our applications, we write the log to the files, then server side supports the api to upload these files.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but I would like to have a solution without involving third-party services. Something like writing a file to the local storage, and then my colleague attaches this file to e-mail. If possible :)